# How do create array in java and pass in graphviz java method?

Tags: java, graphviz

I am using [graphviz with Java](https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java), and I need to loop data array and need to define relationship

```
Graph g = graph("example5").directed().with(node("abc")
        .link(node("xyz")),node("abc")
        .link(node("xyz")));
Graphviz viz = Graphviz.fromGraph(g);
viz.width(200).render(Format.SVG).toFile(new File("example/ex5.svg"));
```

I need to create array that should have multiple node("abc").link(node("xyz")) then pass it to with method

Answer (score 0):

I think doing something like the following should work.

Here I am iterating and creating a node, calling link on the current node and assigning the the node, before reassigning current.

The entire list is then passed to `with`

```
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    Node curr = node(String.valueOf(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        Node next = node(String.valueOf(i+1));
        curr.link(next);
        nodes.add(curr);
        curr = next;
    }

    Graph g = graph("example5").directed().with(nodes);
```